# Build a Mac OS X Cocoa app for running a shell script with arguments

Tags: swift, shell, cocoa, rsync

I'm building a Mac OS X Cocoa app in Swift that uses rsync to backup data. The app has the user select a source and destination in Finder, and it is also able to run the script (with a hard-coded source and destination). But I can't figure out how to pass in the source and destination as arguments to the script.

The script is ran by:

```
@IBAction func runScript(_ sender: NSButton) {
    if sourcePath != nil && destinationPath != nil {
        sender.isEnabled = false
        let path = "/bin/bash"
        let arguments = ["/path/to/script"]
        let task = Process.launchedProcess(launchPath: path, arguments: arguments as! [String])
        task.waitUntilExit()
        sender.isEnabled = true
    }
...
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Unrelated but to get rid of the warning *Forced cast of '[String]' to same type has no effect* delete `as! [String]`. `arguments` is already an array of `String`.

Comment: Actually sourcePath and destinationPath are of type String?, so the cast is necessary. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the arguments to your `arguments` array:

```
    let arguments = ["/path/to/script", sourcePath, destinationPath]
```